# How to show toast in service?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, toast, android-jetpack

I am new in android .I have problem to show toast .

```
val configBuilder = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                val cacheInterval: Long = 0
                configBuilder.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(cacheInterval)
            }
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? can you show your code effort?

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use code like this,

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    String msg="Toast message show";

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){

            Message myMessage=new Message();
            Bundle resBundle = new Bundle();
            resBundle.putString("status", "SUCCESS");
            myMessage.obj=resBundle;
            handler.sendMessage(myMessage);
        }
    };

}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```